# How do i fix a vertex seam?

Tags: modeling, vertices

I have no experience with modelling and i could use some help, i am editing a model from the Source engine, and there happens to be a seam where the arm is, this seam is having a strange lighting effect when used in-game, i'm trying to fix it in Blender with the little tutorials i have (in this case i'm using the Grid Fill tool), but no matter what i do, it doesn't match with the mesh lighting around it, you can notice in the picture that this certain vertex looks out of place:
[image]

Is there a way i can fix it so that the lighting of this vertex matches with what's around it? You probably know what i mean.

Comment: could you also add a picture where you are in edit mode?

Comment: sure here you go: http://i.imgur.com/UWolXUl.png

Comment: Have you recalculated the normals (press **Ctrl+N** in *Edit Mode*)? Removing doubles may help as well (**W-->Remove Doubles**).

Comment: I think it look slike the couple of faces have shading set to flat while the rest is smooth. Select the faces in edit mode and try `W->Shade Smooth`

Comment: None of those methods work, this one vertex is stuck for good, there has to be some other way.